# Correr nodjs en un archivo .htacces

Tags: nodejs, .htaccess, cpanel

quiero correr node.js redirigiendo el acceso en un archivo .htaccess he probado con esto que investigue pero me da error, probablemente lo este ejecutando mal

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^/home2/westwood/myapp/src/index.js$ http://127.0.0.1:80/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/home2/westwood/myapp/src/index.js/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:80/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: node tiene su propio servidor, si estás intentando poner un node detrás de apache lo normal es poner un proxypass/proxypassreverse que enrute las peticiones a la ip y puerto del servidor node

Comment: Se que node tiene su servidor, la primera prueba que hice fue ejecutarlo con forever start accediendo con putty al servidor, ademas de configurar el .htaccess eso me desplegaba mi pagina, obviamente corriendo el servidor node en el puerto 5000 en el servidor, pero al momento de cerrar la ventana de putty todos los procesos se cierran debido a que se ejecutan en segundo plano.

Respecto al enrutamiento lo tengo con express.js, esto es independiente o puedo utilizar ambos ?

Comment: si tenes apache por delante de node, lo mejor es configurar proxypass/proxypassreverse así apache le enruta las peticiones del dominio correspondiente al servidor node en la ip y puerto correspondientes. para correr un servidor node y dejarlo como service podes usar [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)